# wicked_pdf can not find libv8-3.16.14.3 (but installed)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, wicked-pdf, libv8

I just switched from acts_as_flying_saucer to wicked_pdf because I always had problems with this FFI stuff.

Now I'm trying to get this wicked_pdf gem running in my application but if I ran any of the PDF generation methods I get the following error:

> ```
> Failed to execute: "/projectvendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf" -q
> ```
>
> "file:////var/folders/zq/jlkc33yn1v13vr5wmt45m9bm0000gn/T/wicked_pdf20131229-1025-1w96afy.html"
>   "/var/folders/zq/jlkc33yn1v13vr5wmt45m9bm0000gn/T/wicked_pdf_generated_file20131229-1025-1l8wads.pdf"
>   Error: PDF could not be generated! Command Error:
>   /Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in
>   `block in materialize': Could not find libv8-3.16.14.3 in any of the
>   sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) from
>   /Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in`
>   map!' from
>   /Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in
>   `materialize' from
>   /Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in`
>   specs' from
>   /Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in
>   `specs_for' from
>   /Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in`
>   requested_specs' from
>   /Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in
>   `requested_specs' from
>   /Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in`
>   setup' from
>   /Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in
>   `setup' from
>   /Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in`
>   ' from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in
>   `require' from
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in`
>   require'

As I read in other threads I tried the following things yet:

> gem install libv8 -v 3.16.14.3 -- --with-system-v8

Succeeded, but still get the same error.

> gem which libv8
>   /Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3-x86_64-darwin-12/lib/libv8.rb

Seems to be installed correctly? But did not work.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is moving at a downgrade of the version '3.16.14.2'.
Its works fine.